# Linux GPIO mapping

Tags: linux, hardware, gpio

I have a WD-Mycloud, which has an LED and a button as the interface. I can access the LED under `/sys/class/leds/`, but I cannot find where or how the button is mapped.

I know how to access the GPIO pins under `/sys/class/gpio`, but I have no idea which pin the button is attached to.

Any ideas how to figure it out, if it is even possible without the detailed documentation of the hardware?

Thanks

Comment: `watch -d cat /sys/class/gpio/1` and push the button?